# In Oracle PL/SQL can we insert bulk data dynamically?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a requirement to insert bulk data through procedure but the table and columns will be dynamic.
Suppose for one account there is one table and they have their configured columns, similarly there can be 1000 of such accounts, so there will 1000 number tables and their columns.

How can we achieve this in a single procedure?

Comment: Can't you write the SQL dynamically (concatenating strings and variable's contents) and run the final statement with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (which is the syntax for executing dynamic sql queries) ?

Comment: explore your tables and sample insert statements to be implemented, it might help us to provide skeleton

Comment: lets take 3 tables - ort_tab(col1,col2,col3) ort_tab1(col7,col8,col9,col10) ort_tab3(col10,col9) ,so now from java a procedure will be called which will pass the table name along with column name and the respective column data (all data at a time). How can we achieve this?

Comment: Then I think EXECUTE IMMEDIATE might suit your needs. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm

Comment: Insert can be done by EXECUTE IMMEDIATE that is ok.But can we pass multiple data at a time in this situation where the inputs are table name,column name,data (multiple data),can you provide with the procedure skeleton..

Answer (score 0):

A very primitive example, just so you get the feeling:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE yourProcedure (tableName VARCHAR2, 
                             colName1 VARCHAR2, colName2 VARCHAR2, colName3 VARCHAR2) IS
   v_column VARCHAR2(30);
   sql_stmt  VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  sql_stmt := 'SELECT ' || colName1 || ', ' || colName2 || ', ' colName3 || ' FROM ' || tableName 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Node Data Found');
END yourProcedure;
```

You could pass an array of columns instead of 3 columns only, if you the columns you need to select are not known beforehand.
You can also bind variables to the select statement adding the "USING" clause. Refer to documentation examples: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#CHDGJEGD